# Making my SQLite printing method dynamic

Tags: c#, sqlite, csv, printing

I am using SQLite to store the data for my application.
The application has a UI that loads the data from the SQLite database to display it table by table to the user. Basically the user can click left or right and view the other tables one by one.

The user can also click a button that will show a print preview of the data and let them print it. I have this working, but I am having some issues devising a dynamic way to display ANY table on the print preview screen perfectly. My concerns are if some column titles are too long etc, basically how to calculate the size of each column etc. Should I loop through and find the max character size of any text in the entire column and then set the column width to just wider than that or is there an easier way to do this?

I also write the data-table to a comma separated csv file so it might be a better alternative to use an existing solution to print from a csv file if any of you know such a solution then please suggest it!

Anyway here is the currently existing code:

```
// ------------------------ code that gets called when the print button is clicked ----------------------------

// holds the row data
List<string[]> myList = new List<string[]>();

if(ReportPage == 1)
{
    int rowCount = MyTestTable.RowCount;
    for(int i = 0; i <rowCount; i++)
    {
         MyTestTable.SelectedRowIndex = i;
         var row1 = MyTestTable.GetSelectedRow();
         var cols1 = row1.ItemArray;

        string Col1 = cols1[row1.FindIndexOfColumn("Col1")].ToString();
        string Col2 = cols1[row1.FindIndexOfColumn("Col2")].ToString();
        string Col3 = cols1[row1.FindIndexOfColumn("Col3")].ToString();
        string Col4 = cols1[row1.FindIndexOfColumn("Col4")].ToString();
        string Col5 = cols1[row1.FindIndexOfColumn("Col5")].ToString();
        string Col6 = cols1[row1.FindIndexOfColumn("Col6")].ToString();
        string Col7 = cols1[row1.FindIndexOfColumn("Col7")].ToString();
        myList.Add(new string[] { Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7 });
    }

string[] cols = new string[7];
cols[0] = "Col1";
cols[1] = "Col2";
cols[2] = "Col3";
cols[3] = "Col4";
cols[4] = "Col5";
cols[5] = "Col6";
cols[6] = "Col7";

PrintUtility.SetUpDocument("TEST", cols, myList);


}
PrintUtility.TestNewReport();






// ---------------------- plugin code that gets called from the application 

namespace PrintUtility
{

     public class PrintUtility : UserComponentBase
    {
        public PrintDocument document;
        public DataGridView dataGridView;

        public PrintUtility()
        {
            document = new PrintDocument();
            dataGridView = new DataGridView();
        }



        public void SetUpDocument(string title, string[] cols,  List<string[]> rows)
        {
            document = new PrintDocument();
            dataGridView = new DataGridView();
            document.DocumentName = title;
            document.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
            document.PrintPage += PrintPage;

            DataGridView dataGrid = new DataGridView();
            dataGrid.ColumnCount = cols.Length;
            for (int i = 0; i < cols.Length; i++ )
            {
                dataGrid.Columns[i].Name = cols[i];
            }

            foreach(string[] row in rows)
            {
                dataGrid.Rows.Add(row);
            }

            this.dataGridView = dataGrid;
            document.DocumentName = title;
            document.PrintPage += PrintPage;
        }


        public PrintDocument GetDocument()
        {
            return this.document;
        }

        private DataTable ConvertListToDataTable(List<string[]> list)
        {
            // New table.
            DataTable table = new DataTable();

            // Get max columns.
            int columns = 0;
            foreach (var array in list)
            {
                if (array.Length > columns)
                {
                    columns = array.Length;
                }
            }

            // Add columns.
            for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
            {
                table.Columns.Add();
            }

            // Add rows.
            foreach (var array in list)
            {
                table.Rows.Add(array);
            }

            return table;
        }

        public void TestNewReport()
        {
            Report report = new Report(new PdfFormatter());
            FontDef fd = new FontDef(report, "Helvetica");
            FontProp fp = new FontPropMM(fd, 4);
            FontProp fp_Title = new FontPropMM(fd, 6);
            FontProp fp_Word = new FontPropMM(fd, 3);
            fp_Title.bBold = true;

            List<string> columns = new List<string>();
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView.Columns)
            {
                columns.Add(column.Name.ToString());
            }

            List<List<string>> rows = new List<List<string>>();
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.Rows)
            {
                List<string> rowSingle = new List<string>();
                foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        rowSingle.Add(cell.Value.ToString());
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                    }
                }
                rows.Add(rowSingle);
            }

            // AUDIT TABLE ( This way of doing things is not dynamic )
            Page page = new Page(report);
            page.SetLandscape();
            int x = 10;
            int y = 40;
            int pastLength = 0;
            foreach(string col in columns)
            {
                x += ((pastLength * 14) + 31);
                page.Add(x, y, new RepString(fp_Title, col));
                pastLength = col.Length;

            }
            page.Add(0, 52, new RepString(fp_Title, "_________________________________________________________________"));

            /* Dynamic way starting
            int rowX = 10;
            int rowY = 105;
            foreach (List<string> row in rows)
            {
                int pastLength2 = 0;
                foreach (string rowItem in row)
                {
                    page.Add(rowX, rowY, new RepString(fp_Word, rowItem));
                    rowX += ((pastLength * 14) + 31);
                    pastLength2 = rowItem.Length;
                }
                rowY += 30;
            }
             */

            fp_Title.rSizeMM = 8;
            int amountRowsPerPageSoFar = 0;
            int rowY = 80;

            foreach (List<string> row in rows)
            {
                try
                {
                    string iDItem = row[0];
                    page.Add(40, rowY, new RepString(fp_Word, iDItem));

                    string typeItem = row[1];
                    page.Add(120, rowY, new RepString(fp_Word, typeItem));

                    string descriptionItem = row[2];
                    page.Add(190, rowY, new RepString(fp_Word, descriptionItem));

                    string timestampItem = row[3];
                    page.Add(375, rowY, new RepString(fp_Word, timestampItem));

                    string userItem = row[4];
                    page.Add(555, rowY, new RepString(fp_Word, userItem));

                    string stationItem = row[5];
                    page.Add(655, rowY, new RepString(fp_Word, stationItem));

                    string activeItem = row[6];
                    page.Add(775, rowY, new RepString(fp_Word, activeItem));
                    amountRowsPerPageSoFar++;

                    rowY += 30;
                    if (amountRowsPerPageSoFar >= 17)
                    {
                        page = new Page(report);
                        page.SetLandscape();
                        amountRowsPerPageSoFar = 0;
                        rowY = 40;
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }

            RT.ViewPDF(report, "TestReport.pdf");
        }

    }
}
```